# how to show youtube video in an html page with value received via json

Tags: javascript, html

I would like your help.
I have to insert a youtube video whose url is received via json; in particular with

```js
document.getElementById("idframe").innerHTML=myJson.Items[4].value;
```

I get *https://youtu.be/ILmvKC-H1l0*

So far everything ok. To insert the youtube video in an html page I was following [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp).

I just can't get what I want. I get a gray box with the words: It may have been moved, changed, or deleted.
Can you kindly help me?

```js
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
<div class="video"> <iframe id="idframe" width="420" height="345" src="myFunction()"> </iframe> </div> <br>

    <br>

    <script>

    function myFunction() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://vnwcn9gt89.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/book"; 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var myJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       document.getElementById("idframe").innerHTML = myJson.Items[4].value;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: parse out the id (ILmvKC-H1l0 part), then concatenate it onto `www.youtube.com/embed/<id here>`, plop it in an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of changes required in your code:

1. You cannot use shortened URL services like `https://youtu.be/`. Your url should be `https://youtube.com/embed/ILmvKC-H1l0`
2. `innerHTML` won't work for `iframe`. Try below solution

```js
(function() {
  //var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://vnwcn9gt89.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/book";
  /*xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      //Your response for myJson.Items[4].value, should be equal to "https://youtube.com/embed/ILmvKC-H1l0"
      let youtubeUrl = myJson.Items[4].value;
      document.getElementById("idframe").src = youtubeUrl;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();*/
  
  //consider incase you have youtubeUrl as " youtu.be/ILmvKC-H1l0";
  //Extract the id and append it like below
  let returnedYoutubeUrl = "https://youtu.be/ILmvKC-H1l0";
  let id = returnedYoutubeUrl.split("/")[3];
  console.log(id);
  document.getElementById("idframe").src = "https://youtube.com/embed/"+id;
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="video">
      <iframe id="idframe" width="420" height="345"> </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @elfuso commented out Ajax code now to showcase the iframe issue. It should work now. Refer this jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jesujozami/edit?html,js,output

Comment: but I don't have the embed writing because what I am given is https://youtu.be/ILmvKC-H1l0 without embed

Comment: @elfuso you can extract id and append to url directly. please check updated answer

Comment: I'm having the following problem: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'). How can this be solved? I am a neophyte, it is the first time for me

Comment: @elfuso .split() method should be used only in string. If there is no value returned, it will throw undefined; In your case try like this myJson.Items[4].value.split("/")[3]

Comment: Keep giving me the same error. This is what I wrote --> let id = myJson.Items[4].value.split("/")[3];  document.getElementById("idframe").src = "https://youtube.com/embed/"+id;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240584/discussion-between-ganesh-babu-and-elfuso).